# taskcanceledexception

Tags: c#

When I click the button "Add", my data is added to the base, but i encounter a

> taskcanceledexception

Text of exception:

- Exception Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll ("Отменена задача.")   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException

How to fix this exception?
And how i can use a Timer for this?

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReadBase();
    }
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddHumanToList();
        AddToBase();
        listbox.Items.Clear();
        ReadBase();
    }

private async void ReadBase()
    {           
        using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, name, surname FROM myHumanity", sqlConnection);
            try
            {
                await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
                dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    listbox.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(dataReader["id"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(dataReader["name"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(dataReader["surname"]));
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                dataReader?.Close();
                sqlConnection?.Close();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Whats the text of the exception? Include that in your question.

Comment: @Nick, included

Comment: wow i think i found a solution!
I just added a delay  in the biginning of the method ReadBase().

Answer (score 0):

Wow i think i found a solution!
I just added a delay  in the biginning of the method `ReadBase()`.

```
private async void ReadBase()
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, name, surname FROM myHumanity", sqlConnection);
            try
            {
                await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
                dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    listbox.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(dataReader["id"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(dataReader["name"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(dataReader["surname"]));
                }
            }
            catch (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                dataReader?.Close();
                sqlConnection?.Close();
            }
        }   
    }
```